# Distributed Trunking Inconsistent MAC table

Tags: mac-address, hp

I've recently faced a problem in an HPE Distributed-Trunking Switch-to-Switch Square-Topology.

[image: Diagram of normal situation with both hosts working]

Image 1 (shows the essential part of the architecture that consists of 4 switches working in pairs, being switch A1 and A2 the first pair, B1 and B2 the second pair. Both pairs connect switches, servers, clients (not fully drawn for ease of reading).

During normal operations A1, A2, B1 and B2 can ping both `192.168.5.47` and `192.168.6.95` that are used here as "test" hosts.

Sometimes it happens that one of the two hosts gets unreachable ONLY FROM A2, like described in Image 2.

[image: Diagram of issue with one host not responding]

Normal operations are restored by issuing a `clear mac-address Trk1` on switch A2.

These are some relevant output of A2 during normal operations:

```
A2# ping 192.168.5.47
192.168.5.47 is alive, time = 3 ms

A2# ping 192.168.6.95
192.168.6.95 is alive. time = 3 ms

A2#show arp 

IP ARP table
192.168.5.47    aabbcc-111111   dynamic Trk10
192.168.6.95    aabbcc-222222   dynamic Trk10

A2# show mac-address vlan 288
aabbcc-111111   Trk10
aabbcc-222222   Trk10
```

After issue occurs these are some relevant output from A2

```
A2# ping 192.168.5.47
**Request timed out.**

A2# ping 192.168.6.95
192.168.6.95 is alive. time = 3 ms

A2#show arp 
192.168.6.95    aabbcc-222222   dynamic Trk10

A2# show mac-address vlan 288
aabbcc-111111   Trk1
aabbcc-222222   Trk10
```

I've noticed that the erred host (`192.168.5.47`) is seen by A2 on Trk1: it should be on Trk10 instead.

The only way to restore normal operation is by issuing `clear mac-address Trk1` on switch A2.

Can someone figure out one or more possible reason for this behavior?

Follows relevant configurations of A1, A2, B1 and B2.

A1:

```
A1# sh run
Running configuration:
; J9850A Configuration Editor; Created on release #KB.16.03.0004
; Ver #10:08.7f.ff.bb.ff.7c.59.fc.7b.ff.ff.fc.ff.ff.3f.ef:52
hostname "A1"
module A type j9987a
module B type j9990a
module D type j9989a
module F type j9993a
no fault-finder broadcast-storm
no fault-finder bad-driver
no fault-finder bad-transceiver
no fault-finder bad-cable
no fault-finder too-long-cable
no fault-finder over-bandwidth
no fault-finder loss-of-link
no fault-finder duplex-mismatch-hdx
no fault-finder duplex-mismatch-fdx
no fault-finder link-flap
trunk B24,F8 trk1 lacp
trunk D1 trk2 dt-trunk
trunk A21-A22 trk3 dt-trunk
trunk B1-B2 trk4 dt-trunk
trunk D3 trk5 dt-lacp
trunk D22 trk10 dt-lacp
trunk B19,D11 trk11 lacp
trunk D23-D24 trk21 lacp
trunk B20,D12 trk144 lacp
mac-age-time 60
timesync sntp
sntp unicast
no telnet-server
telnet-server listen data
time daylight-time-rule western-europe
time timezone 60
web-management listen data
ip arp-age 1
ip ssh listen data
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 [...]
ip routing
switch-interconnect trk1
[...]
oobm
   disable
   interface disable
   no ip address
   exit
router vrrp
   virtual-ip-ping
   ipv4 enable
   nonstop
   exit
vlan 1
   name [...]
   no untagged [...],Trk10,Trk144
   untagged Trk1, [...]
   no ip address
   jumbo
   disable layer3
   exit
[...]
vlan 288
   name "[…]"
   untagged […],Trk10
   tagged […],Trk1
   ip address 192.168.4.245 255.255.252.0
   ip helper-address 192.168.0.9
   jumbo
   vrrp vrid 2
      virtual-ip-address 192.168.4.244
      priority 101
      enable
      exit
   exit
[...]
vlan 4094
   name "IT-ICS-Keepalive"
   untagged Trk144
   ip address 172.31.255.1 255.255.255.252
   exit
spanning-tree
spanning-tree Trk1 priority 4
[...]
spanning-tree Trk10 priority 4 bpdu-filter
[...]
spanning-tree Trk144 priority 4
spanning-tree pathcost mstp 8021d
[...]
spanning-tree priority 0 force-version rstp-operation
distributed-trunking peer-keepalive vlan 4094
distributed-trunking peer-keepalive destination 172.31.255.2
distributed-trunking role-priority 1
[...]
```

A2:

```
A2# sh run
Running configuration:
; J9850A Configuration Editor; Created on release #KB.16.03.0004
; Ver #10:08.7f.ff.bb.ff.7c.59.fc.7b.ff.ff.fc.ff.ff.3f.ef:52
hostname "A2"
module A type j9987a
module B type j9990a
module D type j9989a
module F type j9993a
no fault-finder broadcast-storm
no fault-finder bad-driver
no fault-finder bad-transceiver
no fault-finder bad-cable
no fault-finder too-long-cable
no fault-finder over-bandwidth
no fault-finder loss-of-link
no fault-finder duplex-mismatch-hdx
no fault-finder duplex-mismatch-fdx
no fault-finder link-flap
trunk B24,F8 trk1 lacp
trunk D1 trk2 dt-trunk
trunk A21-A22 trk3 dt-trunk
trunk B1-B2 trk4 dt-trunk
trunk D3 trk5 dt-lacp
trunk D22 trk10 dt-lacp
trunk B19,D11 trk12 lacp
trunk D23-D24 trk22 lacp
trunk B20,D12 trk144 lacp
mac-age-time 60
timesync sntp
sntp unicast
no telnet-server
telnet-server listen data
time daylight-time-rule western-europe
time timezone 60
web-management listen data
ip arp-age 1
ip ssh listen data
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 [...]
ip routing
switch-interconnect trk1
[...]
oobm
   disable
   interface disable
   no ip address
   exit
router vrrp
   virtual-ip-ping
   ipv4 enable
   nonstop
   exit
vlan 1
   name [...]
   no untagged [...],Trk10,Trk144
   untagged Trk1, [...]
   no ip address
   jumbo
   disable layer3
   exit
[...]
vlan 288
   name "[…]"
   untagged B14-B18,D8,Trk10
   tagged B21,Trk1,Trk12,Trk22
   ip address 192.168.4.246 255.255.252.0
   ip helper-address 192.168.0.9
   jumbo
   vrrp vrid 2
      virtual-ip-address 192.168.4.244
      priority 99
      enable
      exit
   exit
[…]
vlan 4094
   name "IT-ICS-Keepalive"
   untagged Trk144
   ip address 172.31.255.2 255.255.255.252
   exit
spanning-tree
spanning-tree Trk1 priority 4
[...]
spanning-tree Trk10 priority 4 bpdu-filter
[...]
spanning-tree Trk144 priority 4
spanning-tree pathcost mstp 8021d
[...]
spanning-tree priority 1 force-version rstp-operation
distributed-trunking peer-keepalive vlan 4094
distributed-trunking peer-keepalive destination 172.31.255.1
distributed-trunking role-priority 2
[...]
```

B1:

```
B1# sh run
Running configuration:
 ; J8697A Configuration Editor; Created on release #K.16.02.0019
; Ver #10:08.01.81.30.02.34.59.2c.6b.ff.f7.fc.7f.ff.3f.ef:24
hostname "B1"
module 1 type j9548a
module 6 type j9537a
trunk A21-A22 trk1 lacp
trunk F23 trk10 dt-lacp
trunk A19-A20 trk144 lacp
[…]
mac-age-time 60
max-vlans 2048
timesync sntp
sntp unicast
[…]
time daylight-time-rule western-europe
time timezone 60
ip arp-age 1
ip default-gateway […]
switch-interconnect trk1
[…]
vlan 1
   name "DEFAULT_VLAN"
   no untagged […], Trk144
   untagged […],Trk1,Trk10
   ip address 192.168.4.242 255.255.252.0
   jumbo
   exit
[…]
vlan 4094
   name "IT-ICS-Keepalive"
   untagged Trk144
   ip address 172.31.255.1 255.255.255.252
   exit
spanning-tree
[…]
spanning-tree Trk1 priority 4
spanning-tree Trk10 priority 4 bpdu-filter
spanning-tree Trk144 priority 4
no spanning-tree bpdu-throttle
spanning-tree priority 0 force-version rstp-operation
[…]
distributed-trunking peer-keepalive vlan 4094
distributed-trunking peer-keepalive destination 172.31.255.2
distributed-trunking role-priority 1
[…]
```

B2:

```
B2# sh run
Running configuration:
; J8697A Configuration Editor; Created on release #K.16.02.0019
; Ver #10:08.01.81.30.02.34.59.2c.6b.ff.f7.fc.7f.ff.3f.ef:24
hostname "B2"
module 1 type j9548a
module 6 type j9537a
trunk A21-A22 trk1 lacp
trunk F23 trk10 dt-lacp
trunk A19-A20 trk144 lacp
[…]
mac-age-time 60
max-vlans 2048
timesync sntp
sntp unicast
[…]
time daylight-time-rule western-europe
time timezone 60
ip arp-age 1
ip default-gateway […]
switch-interconnect trk1
[…]
vlan 1
   name "DEFAULT_VLAN"
   no untagged […], Trk144
   untagged […],Trk1,Trk10
   ip address 192.168.4.243 255.255.252.0
   jumbo
   exit
[…]
vlan 4094
   name "IT-ICS-Keepalive"
   untagged Trk144
   ip address 172.31.255.2 255.255.255.252
   exit
spanning-tree
spanning-tree Trk1 priority 4
spanning-tree Trk10 priority 4 bpdu-filter
spanning-tree Trk144 priority 4
no spanning-tree bpdu-throttle
spanning-tree priority 1 force-version rstp-operation
[…]
distributed-trunking peer-keepalive vlan 4094
distributed-trunking peer-keepalive destination 172.31.255.1
distributed-trunking role-priority 2
[…]
```

Comment: Is the STP priority of 0 for both A1 and A2 intentional? Additionally, could you post the hosts' MAC-port associations on A2 in working condition and when it's failing?

Comment: Good evening Zac, thank you for your reply. I double-checked and I can't find priority 0 for both A1 and A2... I've set 0 (root) on A1 and 1 on A2. Am I wrong? The hosts' MAC-Address for both A1 and A2 during working and failing conditions are reported above. It basically seems that the unreachable hosts' MAC addresses "go" outside Trunk10 and are seen on Trunk1.

Comment: Well, the diagram above shows prio 0 for both A1 and A2. A2 is 1/4096 then just like B2? Also, I was asking which port the destination host's MAC address are associated with on A1 and A2 - I guess this changes from working to non-working.

Comment: Are you expecting 192.168.4.x to be on both vlan 1 and vlan 288?  There might be additional vlan mismatches further out in the network causing weird mac learning.

Comment: @Zac76. You're right, it's a typo. The diagram shows STP priority 0 for both A1 and A2 (wrong) but the attached configuration is correct with A1 in STP Prio 0 anfd A2 in STP prio 1. The STP bridge is normally A1.

Comment: @cpt_fink. I expect 192.168.4.0/22 being managed in VLAN 1 throug switches B1 a B2 at the top of the diagram (and all their downstream connected switch, named "Other Switch", this part of the network was already operational when I added A1 and A2) and the same subnet being translated and managed in VLAN 288 at the "entrance" in switches A1 and/or A2. Ports D22 on A1 and A2 behave as normal access ports (to VLAN 288) for untagged traffic coming from B1 and/or B2. Of course the tagged portion of traffic (VLAN 101,...) is normally managed as tagged traffic with same VLANID on both ends.

Answer (score 2):

I've also encountered this problem two times allready. Unfortunaltely HPE support was not very helpfull. But my mac-learning problems always related to distributed trunking.
My workaround was to step away from dt.

I recommend to use VSF if possible (V3 Modules and zl2 Switch required among other things: https://higherlogicdownload.s3.amazonaws.com/HPE/MigratedAttachments/E8DDA7C0-AFED-4DF4-B5C7-FD71B705C690-2-AOS-Switch_VSF_Configuration_Guide.pdf - Page 3)

I would treat your old 5406(J8697A) switches as separate units (delete dt), as they do not support VSF. STP would have to do the work here.

Even if this solution is not really practical, i can tell that you don't have the wrong configuration.